# Upload 3 images from an HTML form. Sending the images via Javascript to PHP to upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

Kindly have a look at the screenshot that follows the description and question.
[image]

As you can see there are 3 files that i need to upload from different blocks. These blocks are generated dynamically according to the number of datas in the database. When i have 1 file to be uploaded this works completely fine, i.e, the image preview function *(onChange it shows the preview of the image to be uploaded)* and it is saved to the corresponding folder and subfolder created on run time.

Now when I am trying to add more file uploads neither does the image preview function work nor does the image is saved to folders or subfolders. Please find below the code for the following, please take note of the comments as well for better understanding.

The code is the part of the a PHP where I have added an HTML as well.
HTML form for the images alongwith the javascript for the features.

```
if($x==1){ ?>
        <form id='uploadForm-<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data' method = 'POST' class="form<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>">  
        <input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" />
                <input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img1" onChange="readURL(this);" />
                <input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img2" onChange="readURL(this);" />
        <?php if(!empty($imagepath)){ ?>
            <img id="blah" src="<?php echo $imagepath;?>" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type='button' id = '<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>' class='uploadPicture<?php echo $imgCnt; ?> btn btn-primary' value = 'Upload'>
        <!-- <input type="button" value="upload" class="uploadPicture"  id="upload_btn<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>"/> -->
    </form>
    <?php
    } else{
    ?>
    <form id='uploadForm-<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>' action = '' enctype='multipart/form-data' method = 'POST' class="form<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>">
        <input type="file"  class="image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>" name="img" onChange="readURL(this);" />


        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <input type='button' id = '<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>' class='uploadPicture<?php echo $imgCnt; ?> btn btn-primary' value = 'Upload'>
        <!-- <input type="button" value="upload" class="uploadPicture"  id="upload_btn<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>"/> -->
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function readURL(input) {      
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    //$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).width(300).height(340);
                    $(input).next('img').attr('src', e.target.result).width(300).height(340);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('.uploadPicture<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>').unbind().click( function(e) { 
        var form = $('.form<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>')[0];
        var file_data = $('.image<?php echo $imgCnt; ?>').prop('files')[0];
        var file_path = '<?php echo $testpath; ?>';
        var job_id    = '<?php echo $jobid; ?>';
        var form_data = new FormData(form);                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('filepath', file_path);
        form_data.append('jobid', job_id);
        var edit_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
                url: "file.php",
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result)

                }               
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the PHP that is called by the Javascript for the images to be uploaded.

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
$upload = 'uploads/';
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

    $imagePath = $_POST['filepath'];

    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);  
    $jobid    = $_POST['jobid'];
    $extension = end($temp);
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if(!empty($userid)){
        $time = time();
        $dbimagepath  = $_POST['filepath'] . $time . '.' . $extension;      

                move_uploaded_file($filename, $imagePath . $time . '.' . $extension);  
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO tbl_image (user_id,job_id,image_path) VALUES ('$userid','$jobid','$dbimagepath')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        echo "File Uploaded";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "something went wrong";
        exit;
    }
 ?>
```

Kindly let me know how to accomplish this thing.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP it is required to check that uploaded files are multiple files or single. For that `count()` function will help you do the same.

```
if(count($_FILES)>0){
    //This means there are multiple files uploaded so your required to use a 
    //loop etc.
   foreach($_FILES as $file){
   //Process file upload using $file, $file['tmp_name'] or $file['filepath'] etc.
   }
}
else
{
    //only single file is uploaded
}
```

I believe this is simple way to do what you required...